# how can I plot data with a for loop in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

My database:

Hi everybody, i have the database with columns "LOCATION, "year", "month", "Value" and I would like to show on the same plot three lines (for the value corresponding to the years 2019, 2020, 2021) with on the x axe the month and on the y axe the column "Value" corresponding to that year. I also would like to repeat the same plot for each country contained in my database, how can I do that?

That was my failed attempt:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

url4 = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MmrleW_pe_vopiXK9z5P_EV-CTftsPWV/view?usp=sharing'
path4 = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=' + url4.split('/')[-2]
rb = pd.read_csv(path4)
rbn = rb.loc[:, ["LOCATION", "Time", "Value"]]

rbn['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(rbn['Time'])
yearss = rbn.Time.dt.year.unique()
rbn["year"] = yearss = rbn.Time.dt.year
rbn["Month"] = rbn.Time.dt.month
countryi = rbn.LOCATION.unique()
rbn.Value = round(rbn.Value, 3)
year1 = yearss.unique()
for el in countryi:
  for i in year1:
    x = rbn.loc[(rbn["LOCATION"] == el) & (rbn["year"] == i), ["Month"]]
    y = rbn.loc[(rbn["LOCATION"] == el) & (rbn["year"] == i), ["Value"]]
    plt.plot(x, y)
```

Comment: Why have you tagged pandas, matplotlib, and seaborn, show us your code so far, which library are you using ?  people at Stackoverflow will not write ocde for you

Comment: I was trying to attach my code but i'm a newbie, i will paste in two comments, sorry

Comment: I kindly request you to not post code in the comments.  Figure out how to add code in your question.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?
 for location in df["LOCATION"].unique():    
df.loc[df["LOCATION"]==location].set_index("Month").groupby("year")["Value"].plot()`

Comment: But i need the three lines on the same plot and a different plot for each country, i tried your code and plot everything on the same plot, is it right?

Comment: My bad: for location in df["LOCATION"].unique():
    plt.figure()
    df.loc[df["LOCATION"]==location].set_index("Month").groupby("year")["Value"].plot(

Comment: thank you so much for your effort, I really appreciate it, but I think theere is still some problem, it plots so much lines for each plot (more then only 3 , so more than just the years values)

Comment: Are you sure? in my sample dataframe, it definitely only plots 3 lines per plot. I strongly recommend you to add plt.legend() at the end of the loop. In my case there is one legend for 2019, one for 2020 and one for 2021

Comment: that's my output https://pasteboard.co/RQrprbp4KYG9.png

Comment: Maybe with seaborn:  `sns.relplot(kind='line', x='month', y='value', hue='year', col='LOCATION', col_wrap=4)`

Comment: right, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

sns.relplot(kind='line', x='month', y='value', hue='year', col='LOCATION', col_wrap=4)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).